# Card.io process on device or server?

Tags: ios, card.io

Card.io is great library and we want to use it in our iOS app, but my company PCI DSS team request more information on how card.io works.

1. Does the iOS library process the image on device? or the server does it? The terms and conditions mention server, so I am bit worried that my assumption is invalid
2. If it does work on device, would you able to tell me how does it actually works? on high level of course, just for me to prove to the PCI team that card.io is safe to use

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

card.io does all of its processing on the device. The library contains absolutely no networking code, and does not communicate with any servers. (Many years ago things were different; there might still be some remnant of that situation remaining in a Terms & Conditions document somewhere.)

For an overview of how card.io works, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T9TkkZg1L7s

-- Dave Goldman (former card.io team member)